# Python: create edge list for bipartite graph using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a simple file that lists texts by name and then words that are a part of that text:

```
text,words
ANC088,woods dig spirit controller father treasure_lost
ANC089,controller dig spirit
ANC090,woods ag_work tomb
ANC091,well spirit_seen treasure
```

Working with `pandas` I have this, albeit klugey solution for getting a list of nodes for the two sides of a bipartite graph, one side listing the texts and the other the words, in this case associated with the text:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(open('tales-02.txt', 'r'))
node_list_0 = df['text'].values.tolist()
node_list_1 = filter(None, sorted(set(' '.join(df['words'].values.tolist()).split(' '))))
```

It ain't pretty, but it works, and it's fast enough for my small data set.

What I need is a list of edges between those two nodes. I can this in `csv`, but I can't figure out how to do this in `pandas`. Here's my working `csv`:

```
texts = csv.reader(open('tales-01.txt', 'rb'), delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)

for row in texts:
    for item in row[1:]:
        edge_list.append((row[0], item))
```

*I should note that this version of the input is csv all the way*:

```
ANC088,woods,dig,spirit,controller,father,treasure_lost
ANC089,controller,dig,spirit
```

*I adjusted the file format to make it easier for me to write the `pandas` stuff -- if someone can also show me how to grab the node lists out of the pure `csv` file, that would be awesome.*

I'd rather this be done either all `csv` or all `pandas`. I tried to write a script that would get me the node lists using `csv` but I kept getting an empty list. That's when I turned to `pandas`, which everyone tells me I should be using anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code creates a DataFrame where with the `text` and the `word` columns from your file `tales-01.txt`. It's not very pretty (is there a prettier solution?), but it seems to do the job.

```
df = (pd.read_csv('tales-01.txt',header=None)
      .groupby(level=0).apply(
        lambda x : pd.DataFrame ([[x.iloc[0,0],v]
                                  for v in x.iloc[0,1:]]))
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      .dropna()
      .rename_axis({0:'text',1:'word'},axis=1)
      )
```

Here is a second solution based on the same idea that uses `zip` instead of the for loop. It might be faster.

```
def my_zip(d):
  t,w = d.iloc[0,0],d.iloc[0,1:]
  return pd.DataFrame(zip([t]*len(w), w)).dropna()

df = (pd.read_csv('tales-01.txt',header=None)
      .groupby(level=0)
      .apply(my_zip)
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      .rename_axis({0:'text',1:'word'},axis=1)
      )
```

The result is the same in both cases:

```
     text           word
0  ANC088          woods
1  ANC088            dig
2  ANC088         spirit
3  ANC088     controller
4  ANC088         father
5  ANC088  treasure_lost
6  ANC089     controller
7  ANC089            dig
8  ANC089         spirit
```

Comment: If I add `edge_list = df.values.tolist()` below the second answer above, I get what I need. I am going to spend the next day or so studying this bit of code to understand how it works, but this is a working solution. I like that you used `tales-01`. Any suggestion on how to use that for the node lists? That is, is there a way to tell `pandas` to use the first item in a row for 1 column and to put everything else in a row in a second column? (SO etiquette means I should probably make this a second question?)

Comment: For anyone curious, here's the consolidated code I came up with -- I'm not sure how pretty the `list(set( *.tolist)) is, but it works and I wrote it! (It's below because I can't figure out how to do a code block in the comments and I didn't want to be so arrogant as to claim to answer my own questions after @dov-grobgeld 's great response.

Comment: ````df = (pd.read_csv('tales-01.txt', header=None)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame ([[x.iloc[0,0],v] for v in x.iloc[0,1:]]))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .dropna()
    .rename_axis({0:'text',1:'word'},axis=1)
    )
edges = df.values.tolist()
nodes_0 = list(set(df['text'].values.tolist()))
nodes_1 = list(set(df['word'].values.tolist()))````